# Pandas Convert Multiple Columns to Rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
     code    title      amount_1  amount_2   currency_1    currency_2
0     246       ex           500       550          USD           GBP
1     300       am           200       250          USD           GBP
2     315      ple           300       325          USD           GBP
```

I'd like to get this into the format

```
code    title   amount   currency
246        ex      500        USD
246        ex      550        GBP
```

All of the currencies are the same. How can I get this format? I've tried using melt and reset_index, but neither seemed to do exactly what I need.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                      stubnames=['amount','currency'], 
                      i=['code','title'], 
                      j='measure', sep='_').reset_index()

print (df1)
   code title  measure  amount currency
0   246    ex        1     500      USD
1   246    ex        2     550      GBP
2   300    am        1     200      USD
3   300    am        2     250      GBP
4   315   ple        1     300      USD
5   315   ple        2     325      GBP
```

Comment: You seem to be everywhere with great answers. Thank you for this!